# Breaking up large file, but adding header to each subsequent file

Tags: python, csv

I'm using the following code to break up a large CSV file and I want the original CSV header to be written to each smaller CSV file. The problem I am having, though, is that the current code seems to skip a line of data for each smaller file. So in the example below Line 51 wouldn't be written to the smaller file (code modified from http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578045-split-up-text-file-by-line-count/). It seems to skip that line or perhaps it's being overwritten by the header:

```
import os

filepath = 'test.csv'
lines_per_file=50

lpf = lines_per_file
path, filename = os.path.split(filepath)
with open(filepath, 'r') as r:
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    try:
        w = open(os.path.join(path, '{}_{}{}'.format(name, 0, ext)), 'w')
        header = r.readline()
    for i, line in enumerate(r):
            if not i % lpf:
                #possible enhancement: don't check modulo lpf on each pass
                #keep a counter variable, and reset on each checkpoint lpf.
                w.close()
                filename = os.path.join(path,
                                        '{}_{}{}'.format(name, i, ext))
                w = open(filename, 'w')
                w.write(header)
            w.write(line)
    finally:
        w.close()
```

Comment: So, original header is line 1 in original file? Then why you not write it to the first `chunk` file?

Comment: For me, your code works just fine on Python 2.7.11 and 3.5.1. (After correcting the indentation of the for loop.)

Comment: But with Python 2.7.11, inconsistent newlines produce wrong line counts. (`\r` is not recognized as newline on Windows 7.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) to split the large csv file:

> **Lets create a csv file having 500 rows and four columns using pandas:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(500,4), columns=['a','b','c','d'])
df.to_csv('large_data.csv', index=False)
```

> **Lets split the large_data.csv in to multiple csv files of each having 50 rows:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('large_data.csv', chunksize=50)
i = 1
for chunk in df:
    chunk.to_csv('split_data_'+str(i)+'.csv', index=False)
    i = i+1
```

> **This would have produced the following resultant files:**

[image]